# Where can I find documentation for AMDGPU-PRO?

Tags: graphics, radeon, gpu, amdgpu-pro

I do not know if this is the correct forum category - I'm sorry if it's wrong.

I just created a small script that changes the speed of my GPU fans... The process took quite long though since I basically had to guess my way to the place where fan speeds are derived from when AMDGPUPRO is installed (/sys/class/drm/card0/device/hwmon/hwmon2/pwm1)!

Is there some documentation of sorts that I missed that would explain what all the different AMDGPUPRO files do, if I ever were to write a similar application in the future?

Comment: You will want to read this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ATI "Is there some documentation of sorts that I missed that would explain what all the different AMDGPUPRO files do" I doubt we can answer this. Is that not 3rd party closed software(?) You might be able to find docs on the opensource version though (the closed one uses the open one as its base)

Comment: @Rinzwind It is 3rd party, but not necessarily closed software. Parts of the Pro driver are closed, but the core portion of it is just a newer version of the open source amdgpu driver. The `/sys/` interface should be almost exactly the same for both.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not sure where such documentation would be. Perhaps there is something in the Linux kernel tree that would help here.

Comment: @dobey I know this is an old answer, but you were right. There was a bit of information there!

Comment: @Dreuhn Great. I've posted a bit more lengthy version of that as an answer if you'd like to accept it as the answer for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For open source drivers included in the upstream kernel, the interfaces should generally be documented somewhere under the `./Documentation/` sub-directory of the Linux kernel source tree. As `amdgpu` is an open driver in the upstream tree, there should be some documentation included there for it as well. However, the *Pro* driver include extra proprietary components, as well as newer versions of some open source components, so there may be differences between what interfaces are provided by it, and by the version of the `amdgpu` driver in the kernel version you are running.

Beyond that, it's basically up to driver developers to provide such documentation, and many proprietary drivers just do not provide any such information.